# Serializer vs Renderer in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm having trouble noticing the difference between serializer and renderer in django rest framework.

I thought serializer is for converting the python object to JSON (or other data formats). But renderers, such as JSONRenders, are said to do the simillar thing, e.g. making(rendering) JSON object!

Could you tell me the difference between those two?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A serializer doesn't know anything about any output formats. It just takes your models and converts then into python data structures It's then the job of the renderer to output that data in the appropriate format.

(A serializer also has the job of converting the posted data back to model instances, validating it in the process.)

Comment: Umm.. I don't understand this sentence ; 'It just takes your models and converts then into python data structures ' Here, isn't the model supposed to be also python object even before the conversion happens? Is it a data other than python objects? Doesn't django handle models in python ?

Comment: @rhee I think OP means that the serialiser will convert python objects (instances of your model classes) into a native python data types. That is, a format that would could be understood by another Python script without needing to import your model files.

Answer (score 2):

Serializers simply convert to python data structures.

Where **Renderer** has multiple purposes

- JSONRenderer: Renders the request data into JSON, using utf-8
  encoding.
- TemplateHTMLRenderer: Renders data to HTML, using Django's
  standard template rendering.
- StaticHTMLRenderer: A simple renderer
  that simply returns pre-rendered HTML.
- BrowsableAPIRenderer: Renders
  data into HTML for the Browsable API.
- AdminRenderer: Renders data
  into HTML for an admin-like display.
- HTMLFormRenderer: Renders data
  returned by a serializer into an HTML form.
- MultiPartRenderer: This
  renderer is used for rendering HTML multipart form data.

You may also make custom renderer.

See the [link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/) for details information.

Comment: Serializers don't convert to JSON.